How can I access the bearings in this boiler fan for replacement?
Can anyone explain how to get to the bearings in this boiler fan? To access the bearings, it
appears that the fan blades need to be removed from the axle. There is no lock washer or set screw. The blades are made of plastic. Would using a puller deform the blade?




Hard to tell from the photo, but if that is a metal wedge or spring holding the impeller, then you might try a few things:


First, try gently prying underneath the impeller edge with a wide flat-blade screwdriver, working your way around the edge, or gently use a gear puller. N.B., plastic breaks easily; as you state, the gear puller might be more likely to snap it than the screwdriver.
If that fails, try to remove that "wedge", if it's not a spring. Perhaps needle-nose pliers could get a grip, or a rotary tool could dig a divot, to give an awl purchase to pry against the shaft, as fulcrum.
Finally, try tapping the shaft gently with hammer and punch -- the impeller may be the only thing holding the shaft in place.


Thank-you @DrMoishe!  Given the potential difficulty of repair, I replaced the whole fan assembly with a new one I purchased at reasonable cost.  Since the original fan is still functional (but makes noise from time to time), I will keep it as a back-up in case needed in the future.
